# Two paragraphs next to eachother

Tags: paragraphs

I wanted to know if there was any way of creating two paragraphs of equal size next to eachother with a vertical line in the middle. My goal is to put 2 small and similar proofs in mathmode in a smaller space than the align environnement would give.

Comment: `\begin{tabular}{p{<width>} | p{<width>}}<proof 1>&<proof 2>\end{tabular}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I just wanted to know if it is possible to cut the page in half while doing so, or even create an environnement that takes an argument which is the number of divison you want to make on the page.

Comment: Look at the [tabularx package](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx?lang=en) and its `X` column specifier, or at [parcolumn package](https://ctan.org/pkg/parcolumns)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add two minipages and set their width close to half of a page. `\hfill` can work as space separator or `\hfill\vrule\hfill` if you want an extra vertical bar

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[nopar]{kantlipsum}

\newlength\pindent
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength\pindent{\parindent}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\twoproofs}{+m+m}{%
    \noindent%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
        \setlength\parindent{\pindent}#1
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill\vrule\hfill%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
        \setlength\parindent{\pindent}#2
    \end{minipage}}


\begin{document}
\kant[1][1-2]

\bigskip

\twoproofs{%
    \begin{proof}\kant[4][1]\end{proof}}{%
    \begin{proof}\kant[5][2]\end{proof}}

\bigskip

\kant[1][3-4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `setlength\parindent{\pindent}` ? I removed it, and the errors with it, while having the same result.

Comment: It's not critical. However, `minipage` cancels `\parindent` so we have no indentation inside. It has to be set manually if we want to keep paragraph indentation in minipages. This is what it does.

Comment: I saved the default `\parindent` value in a custom length name `\pindent`. Then, this value is used to set `\parindent` inside minipages.